# What downloading speed i should expect?

Tags: download, speed

I have a 1 MB dsl connection and i am getting around 100 kb/s downloading speed. I was wondering if its right or i should expect more?

Infact my real question is what it really mean by 1 MB internet connection? To me its like my ISP divide 1 MB for 8-10 people and everyone then gets around 100 kb/s?

This is my ISP home page, you can see for more details if anyone has any confusion what i am really looking for.

http://www.ptcl.com.pk/contentp.php?NID=190

Comment: what do these speed tests tell you?  http://www.speakeasy.net/speedtest/ and http://www.dslreports.com/stest

Comment: are your router ADSL2+ enabled ?

Comment: @Revolter I dont think so, its simple ASDL

Comment: I think you mean you have a 1Mb connection, not a 1MB

Comment: @MarkM i think you are right, but you know that when they advertise they use the word "mega bytes" not "mega bits" and now i can see why i am getting 100 kb/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISPs typically advertise in MegaBITS per second, you're measuring in KiloBYTES per second. And then, you never get everything you're paying for, so 100kB/s on a 1Mb line seems about right to me, unfortunately!

Example: I have an 8 megabit/s line, meaning I should get 1 megabyte/s. I get close, sometimes, but most of the time I get about 2-300kb/s.

Comment: yah thats basically confusing! if there advertisement is MBs then why we are getting speed in Kbs?

Comment: Because ISPs want to make their services look better, but nobody measures anything in bits, they're *too small*. It's just another way for companies to try and trick us into thinking we're getting more than we are - but they all do it, so it doesn't really affect our choices! (Only our hopes and dreams :()

Comment: Every ISP I have ever known has measures speeds in either kilobits or megabits, NEVER kilobytes or megabytes.  Conversion factors and line protocol waste apply as everyone has said.

Answer (score 4):

1 Megabits (Mb) = 1024 kilobits (kb), To convert to kilobytes (kB), you simply divide by 8, since there are 8 bits in a byte.

you should have arround 1024 / 8 = **128** kilobytes (kB) download speed, so 100 kB is great.

Comment: he said he has 1MB internet connection speed not 1Mb

Comment: thats what's the IPS are saying, I think they were just writing in uppercase ... marketing ...

Comment: I think you are right in your calculations, its megabits not megabytes! But these advertising companies just confuse you on TV when they say its megabytes!

Comment: In general, they don't say Megabytes. If you look on the website linked, it says "1Mbps". Most consumers simply don't pay attention to Mbps vs MBps.

Comment: @Andrew
Yah you are right.

Answer (score 2):

With line-protocol overhead, you should count 10 bits for the transmission of each 8-bits byte.

So, if your speed is 1 Mb/s (rather than 1MB as you wrote), then you're getting exactly the right speed as promised by your ISP.