# download speed is fast but transfer rate is slow

Tags: download, internet-connection, data-transfer

I've just changed ISP and I'm pretty disappointed with the transfer rate. 
My previous connection has a download speed of 1.08 Mb/s as seen from this site: http://speedtest.net and the download transfer rate is about 100kb/s for sites that doesn't limit their bandwidth. 
Now my connection has about 2Mb/s download speed but the transfer rate is dancing from 20-50kb/s . I was expecting a speed much higher than this because of the download speed that I'm getting when I'm testing. 
The question is what's the difference between transfer rate and download speed, is it normal to have a high download speed but low transfer rate, should the download speed be proportional to the transfer rate?

Answer (score 3):

If by Download speed you mean advertised or speedtest download number and by transfer rate you mean speed you get when downloading a file, then yes, generally, all else remaining the same, if one increases the other should as well.  File download rate(kBps or kilobytes ps) has a theoretical max at 1/8 th of Download speed( Kbps or kilobits ps).

There could be ofcourse other factors at play. For instance did you verify the 2Mbps Number at speedtest.net? Is the new transfer speed tested on the same server as earlier?

There are a few other posts which seem to be about similar issues, which might have solutions that could help -

[What downloading speed i should expect?](https://superuser.com/questions/82307/what-downloading-speed-i-should-expect?rq=1)

[Download Speed is consistently at 16kbps](https://superuser.com/questions/243928/download-speed-is-consistently-at-16kbps?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

It's the difference between bits and bytes.

```
1 byte = 8 bits
```

2 Mb/s is 2 Mega Bits/sec

```
2Mega Bits/s = 2x1024 Kilo Bits/s
             = 2048 Kilo Bits/s
             = 2048/8 Kilo Bytes/s
             = 256 Kilo Bytes/s
```